# Form should load through ajax call instead of calling action class

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee

In this scenario, Page is loaded by calling action class so, I need to convert this to ajax call instead of action class. Now, I have make the changes such that page should get loaded through ajax call instead of calling action class.
Can some one please help me in converting this. I am new to ajax.

Below JSP code calling action class:

```
     <form action="/OppID" class="XXX-column-form xxx-styled-form" method="post"
     style="border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-top: none;height: 690px; ">
```

Action Class:

```
     public class OppID extends DispatchAction{
     public ActionForward siebelData(ActionMapping mapping,
           ActionForm form, 
           HttpServletRequest request, 
           HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{


                      //some code here

                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires jquery.  You have a form, so I'm assuming you're posting to it using a submit button.  In that button, put an onclick and point to a javascript method, like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitViaAjax()" />
```

then give your form an ID

```
<form id="myFormsID" action="/OppID" class="XXX-column-form xxx-styled-form" method="post"
     style="border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-top: none;height: 690px; ">
```

then create that javascript method and do the following to submit via ajax:

```
function SubmitViaAjax() {
    $.post("/OppID", $('#myFormsID').serialize(), function (response) {

        $('#aDivToPutItIn').html(response);

    });
}
```

remember to create the "aDivToPutItIn" element, or change that to whatever element you want the response to get loaded into via ajax.

Comment: Hi, I want to make the ajax call for loading the Page instead of action class. In the below tag I made the changes :<form action="" class="xxx-column-form xxx-styled-form" method="post" style="border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-top: none;height: 690px; ">. Now how to make the Ajax call so, that page get loaded?